# Evaluating data passed through multiprocess pipe

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe

I noticed data received through a multiprocess pipe can not be evaulated directly. In the example below, the code gets stuck in the child process.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def child(conn):
    while True:
        if conn.recv()==1:
            conn.send(1)

        if conn.recv()==2:
            conn.send(2)

    conn.close()

def main():

    parent_conn, child_conn = mp.Pipe()
    p = mp.Process(target=child, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()

    while True:
        parent_conn.send(1)
        print(parent_conn.recv())

    p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But if I assign a variable to conn.recv() in the child process, as shown below. Then everything works.

```
def child(conn):
    while True:

        x = conn.recv()
        
        if x==1:
            conn.send(1)

        if x==2:
            conn.send(2)

    conn.close()
```

I assume this is because the parent and child processes are running concurrently, so the data being passed should only be evaluated as they are received. Is this the the cause?

I am running Python 3.7 on Windows 10.

Comment: Your code ‘locks up’ because the code in the client calls conn.recv() twice every time round the loop. Your revised code only calls conn.recv() once each time around the loop. The second call to conn.recv() doesn’t respond because it receives 1 not 2, so the parent stops waiting for a response.

Comment: BTW the code is stopped in both child and parent: parent is waiting for a response it will never get, and child is waiting on if conn.recv()==1. Simple to debug by adding print statements after each child recv and parent send.

Comment: barny, thank you for the explanation. appreciate the help.